# Android: Inject_Events

Tags: android, events, permissions, inject

I have created a custom event. I want to execute that event, and I figured I would need Instrumentation.sendPointerSync(event) to execute it.
However, I want to execute this event in other apps as well (when my main app is running in background).
I gave INJECT_EVENTS permission, but it does not work.

I do not want to sign my app as system app, nor I want to work as root. (As I will be distributing my app). Any other way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no other way. You already mentioned the two possibilities and there is no third option to inject events to the whole android system